# Python async, future behaviour

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
from asyncio import Future
import asyncio

async def plan_fut(future_obj):
    print('future started')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    future_obj.set_result('Future completes')

def create() -> Future:
    future_obj = Future()
    asyncio.create_task(plan_fut(future_obj))
    return future_obj

async def main():
    future_obj = create()
    result = await future_obj

    print(result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Result

```
future started
Future completes
```

If I change function create to

```
async def create() -> Future:
    future_obj = Future()
    asyncio.create_task(plan_fut(future_obj))
    return future_obj
```

result is

```
<Future pending>
future started
```

1. I understand the case 1 where create is blocking and main awaits for future object
2. I don't understand the case 2, when create is async, why does main behave weird, shouldn't it wait for future to complete in this case as well?

Comment: Every `async` or future needs one corresponding `await`. In your second case you first need to `await` the `async` function, before you get the future, which you then also need to `await`.

Comment: Thanks @deceze , that fixes the issue: 
```
future_obj = await create()
```